# Css Sprites and IE8 problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I’m working on a site which has almost 30 background images, so I decided to make a "sprite image", and use the `background-position` attrib in CSS.

In FF, and Opera the whole design shows correctly, but under IE8, I get a problem. It seems IE8 doesn’t position the image correctly.  I see a thin line in a few places between the images. Sometimes when I zoom in with mouse scroll the line disappears, then shows again...

For example, I use sprites something like this:

```
#index {
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        width:327px;
        height:57px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        background-image:url(images/sprites/sprites_left.jpg);
        background-position:0px -340px;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
```

Is this an IE8 bug? What should I do? Leave the design split into 30 background images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking I would [leave a gap of a few pixels](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/03/27/css-spriting-tips/) (or more) between each tile in your sprite image.

Comment: and you think this is the problem? i try i, make a new sprite image with "gaps"

Comment: “Sometimes when I zoom in with mouse scroll, then the line disappears” — I think I’ve seen something like that in Chrome when zooming.

Comment: Scunliffe: It seems you have right. When i recreated the "spirte img" with 2px space the problem gone..thank for the tipp.

Comment: no problem... any time. I tried to find a blog post that discusses the issues (across browsers) with large widths/heights and small gaps but I haven't found it yet.  I'll follow up with it later when I find it. ;-)